# Highcharts yAxis title aligns horizontal instead of vertical (default behavior)

Tags: highcharts

In my highcarts implementation on a legacy frames/asp application I am facing an issue where the yAxis title aligns as horizontal instead of vertical (default behavior), I tried to use the highcarts Rotate property, also tried to implement a solution involving .CSS but the title does not rotate

Answer (score 1):

It was a tricky investigation that lead me to the solution to solve this problem, my application is using  the meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5" for compatibility. This is causing rotate Highcharts property to not work. This took me a lot of time so I thought I should post this as it may help anyone who comes across this issue.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with the solution you found. That is very helpful for the community.